# memory deallocation with delete [] for 2d array with one dimension constant

Tags: c++, malloc

I allocated a 2D array using new like this

```
  int (*arr)[2] = new int[x][2];
```

x is calculated at runtime.

How should I deallocate this memory? I tried

```
delete [] *arr[0];
delete [] *arr[1];
```

However, valgrind says that their were 13 allocs and 14 frees.

Comment: This is for a class and we haven't covered vectors. I wish we could use them.

Comment: "Use vectors" is not an answer to literally every pointer-related question ever.

Comment: @Barry just 99% of them..:)

Comment: @Barry It's not an answer it's a comment. Students need to know that's not how you write code in the real world if you want to be safe and productive. It's 2014 not 1994.

Comment: @NeilKirk In the real world, I use pointers way more frequently than I use vectors. Which isn't to say I don't use vectors. I just use the right tool for the problem. Which vector is not uniformly.

Comment: @Barry The array is allocated dynamically to unknown size. Why wouldn't you use a vector? Example: `vector<array<int, 2>>`

Comment: @NeilKirk It depends entirely on what he's actually doing with `arr`. The real question is: do you really think it's not important to learn the answer to this question?

Comment: @Barry Could you give an example in which vector would be an inappropriate solution for this? I don't think it's important for a beginner to learn how to dynamically allocate C-style 2d arrays of non-constant size because there are easier and less error prone methods available. In my career I've never written code like that and never see that I ever will.

Comment: I never knew you could do new[x][y].. I was under the impression you had to allocate each index :S

Comment: @Brandon only works if `y` is known at compile-time. There's a proposal for C++17 to support run-time `y`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use one `new[]`, so you should use one `delete[]`:

```
delete[] arr;
```

The `delete[]` form applies to any `new[]`; there aren't separate cases for `new T[x]` as for `new T[x][2]` or anything.  An expression like `new T[x][2]` is actually a single array `new` where the array element has type "array of 2 T's".